# Is it possible to fetch helm list from cluster which is deployed by other user

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

If another user was deployed a helm chart. If I connect to that cluster & used helm list It's not showing the releases. How can I fetch list of releases in helm which is deployed by another user for same cluster.

If possible how can we do that.

Comment: Are you both using the same namespace?  Are you using Helm 3, or the obsolete Helm 2?

Comment: I had set up Argo CD to deploy my Helm charts, but it doesn't actually deploy them using Helm, so there was no release listed. Conveniently, Argo CD has its own diff tool.

Answer (score 5):

helm ls should return all the releases installed in your cluster.
Maybe the issue is that another user has installed his chart on a different namespace?
Try running `helm ls -A` and see if it returns.